# Create a User Object with a Call to TastyPie API

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have a Tastypie resource for a model extended from django.contribut.auth's User model (just a few extra fields). Here's the resource code:

```
class CustomerResource(ModelResource):

    locations = fields.ToManyField('device.resources.LocationResource',
            'location_set', null=True)
    current_location = fields.ToOneField('device.resources.LocationResource',
            'current_location', null=True)
    default_location = fields.ToOneField('device.resources.LocationResource',
            'default_location', null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Customer.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'customers'
        validation = CleanedDataFormValidation(form_class=RegistrationForm)
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'patch', 'delete']
        authorization = Authorization()
        excludes =['is_superuser', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'password', 'last_login',]
        filtering = {
            'location': ('exact'),
        }

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        bundle.data['username'] = bundle.data['email']
        return super(CustomerResource, self).obj_create(bundle, **kwargs)
```

I want to be able to make a POST to the API with some JSON gathered from a form (it can't just be form data because I need to do some processing) to create the user. Here is my Django code that posts up to the API:

```
    payload = {}
    payload['email'] = request.POST['username']
    payload['username'] = request.POST['username']
    payload['password1'] = request.POST['password1']
    payload['password2'] = request.POST['password2']
    payload = json.dumps(payload)

    customer = requests.post(self.base_url + '/v1/customers/', data=payload, headers=headers)
```

This posts a customer fine -- it exists in the API's database. However, its password for some reason is not registered. The password attribute is blank, whereas if I create a user locally in the API's database, the password appears as an encrypted hash. The has_usable_password field is set to false. The same thing happens if I try `payload['password'] = request.POST['password1']`. Any suggestions?

My Customer model:

```
class Customer(AbstractUser):

    current_location = models.ForeignKey('device.Location',
            null=True, blank=True, related_name='customers_present')
    default_location = models.ForeignKey('device.Location',
            null=True, blank=True, related_name='default_customers')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(self.username)
```

Comment: What's your `Customer` model?

Comment: It inherits from django.contrib.auth.models.User. Added above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Customer` model has inherited a custom `UserManager` manager attribute named `objects`. It allows you to easily create `Customer` instances and takes care of the password encryption.

You have to override the `obj_create` method in your `CustomerResource`:

```
class CustomerResource(ModelResource):

    locations = fields.ToManyField('device.resources.LocationResource',
            'location_set', null=True)
    current_location = fields.ToOneField('device.resources.LocationResource',
            'current_location', null=True)
    default_location = fields.ToOneField('device.resources.LocationResource',
            'default_location', null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Customer.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'customers'
        validation = CleanedDataFormValidation(form_class=RegistrationForm)
        list_allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
        detail_allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'patch', 'delete']
        authorization = Authorization()
        excludes =['is_superuser', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'password', 'last_login',]
        filtering = {
            'location': ('exact'),
        }

    def obj_create(self, bundle, **kwargs):
        bundle.obj = self._meta.object_class.objects.create_user(
            username=kwargs['username'],
            email=kwargs['email'],
            password=kwargs['password1'],
        )
        return bundle
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why? Where do I put the ModelManager? How do I use it?

Comment: @user1427661, I have rephrased the answer, hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Hm. My **kwargs argument seems to be empty despite passing the parameters in, resulting in a key error when I try to do the override you describe above.

Comment: Try with `bundle.data` dictionary.